# Let $T: V \to V$ be a linear operator with $\lambda$ an eigenvalue of $T$. Then $f(\lambda)$ is an eigenvalue of $f(T)$ for all $f\in F[x]$. Converse?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let $T: V \to V$ be a linear operator and $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $T$. Then $f (\lambda)$ is an eigenvalue of $f(T)$ for all $f \in F[x]$ where $ F $ is a field .

My question is: when the reverse of this statement is true?

What should be the condition needed?

Comment: What is $F[T]$?

Comment: Try this with $f(t) = t^2$.

Comment: @Meowdog ... I assume $F$ is a field and $F[T]$ are the polynomials with coefficients in $F$.

Comment: If $f(\lambda)$ is an eigenvalue of $f(T)$ for every polynomial $f$, then $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$, witnessed by taking $f(t)=t$.

Comment: @GEdgar That is clearly meant, but it overloads $T$ which was already the name of a linear transformation. It should really be $F[t]$ or $F[x]$...

Answer (score 2):

The converse of

> Let $T$ be a linear operator and let $\lambda$ be a scalar. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$, then for every polynomial $f(t)\in F[t]$ we have that $f(\lambda)$ is an eigenvalue of $f(T)$.

is

> Let $T$ be a linear operator and let $\lambda$ be a scalar. If for every polynomial $f(t)\in F[t]$ we have that $f(\lambda)$ is an eigenvalue of $f(T)$, then $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$.

This statement is *always* true: because the condition holds for $f(t)=t$, so the premise tells us that $f(\lambda)=\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $f(T)=T$.

Comment: Thank you . Now I am changing the question . Suppose f( λ ) is an eigenvalue of  f(T) . Then is λ  is an eigenvalue of T ? Here I am not assuming for all f  belongs to F[ x ] . Can you please help me solve this concept ?

Comment: @MathLearner You don't ask an entirely different question in comments, so no, I'm not going to answer that.

Comment: Okay . Sorry for that .

Answer (score -1):

What if $f \equiv 0$?
You can take $T$ such that $0$ is not an eigenvalue of $T$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).